# Odoo message_post messages not showing up in UI

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

We're using Odoo 15. I've tested this in the webshell on Odoo.sh as well as through the model's method. My code I'm trying is below. It'll create the messages and I can retrieve them through the webshell and read the body, but for some reason the webshell- and method-created messages do not appear in the UI. Additionally, messages that I create in the UI do not appear in the webshell.

Any ideas?

```
messages = [message for message in record.message_ids]
for message in messages:
    print(message.body)
```

This successfully prints all messages created in the webshell, through the methods in the model's code, or on record creation. However, it does not show the UI-created messages.

```
body = 'test webshell body'
record.message_post(body=body, message_type='comment')
```

This creates a message that I can then retrieve through the webshell, but does not show up in the UI.